# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException on calling View.draw(Canvas) method

Tags: java, android

I am trying create bitmap from a Linear Layout in a asynctask(). Please find the code here:

```
while (running) {
        count++;
        v1.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));//I am getting exception here
        //sleep thread to give some lag
    try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println("Bitmap : [ " + count + " ] >>>>>>>> SAVED. ");

    }
```

And I am getting the error as:

```
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 1, 1
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.text.PackedIntVector.getValue(PackedIntVector.java:70)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.text.DynamicLayout.getLineTop(DynamicLayout.java:592)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.text.Layout.getLineForVertical(Layout.java:1015)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.text.Layout.getLineRangeForDraw(Layout.java:460)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:198)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.widget.Editor.onDraw(Editor.java:1306)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5163)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14465)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14350)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3103)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2940)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:14468)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at com.sample.ScreenShotTask.takeScreenshots(ScreenShotTask.java:75)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at com.sample.ScreenShotTask.doInBackground(ScreenShotTask.java:35)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at com.sample.ScreenShotTask.doInBackground(ScreenShotTask.java:1)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
04-21 16:29:46.768: E/AndroidRuntime(20850):    ... 4 more
```

***Can anybody help?***

Comment: are you calling ui stuff in non ui thread? if so, no no no, dont do that

Comment: Added code has nothing which can throw IndexOutOfBoundsException. @pskink What is the relation of IndexOutOfBoundsException with ui/ non ui thread?

Comment: @ErsinGülbahar v1 is my LinearLayout from which i want to create bitmap.

Comment: @PankajKumar i dont know, but i know that you cannot call ui related stuff in non ui thread

Comment: @PankajKumar But error is there :(. View.draw(Canvas) method renders calling view on the passed canvas object. But my problem is that v1 is also being updated simultaneously. I need help to rectify this problem.

Comment: What is at line number 75 into ScreenShotTask.java

Comment: @PankajKumar v1.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));//I am getting exception here

Comment: @PankajKumar as per the developer guideline http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29 , we can see that view must have already done a full layout before this function is called but in our case it is changing continuously

Comment: I handled this problem temporarily by aplying catch clause for ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You canuse try catch block for this exception. Like below :

```
while (running) {
    count++;
    try {
        v1.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
    } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(30);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }

    System.out.println("Bitmap : [ " + count + " ] >>>>>>>> SAVED. ");
}
```